# A way to convert numbers to seconds

Tags: python, python-3.x, numbers

I know this is not the best way to explain what I want to achieve, but I will try to do it by defining my desired output.

The context: An object passes Point A at 6:58 (format is: minute:second) and passes Point B at 7:12. Calculate the time taken to get from Point A to B.

Logically, you'd take B time away from A time to get your result. I expected:
`0.14` because it takes the object 14 seconds but got `0.54` because Python by default won't know that I need it to calculate in seconds format, where the 59 is maximum before you reach a new leading number.

My code is as simple as:

```
A=6.58
B=7.12
print(B-A)
```

Comment: Why would you represent a time with floats? Use a data structure that accurately represents the format, and if you really must use floats, then wrap the logic in a class which will manage it.

Comment: I need to represent time with floats because there is more context to my code than shown in the question. Also please do explain what I can do with classes. I am pretty new to Python.

Comment: research the datetime module, this will probably suit your purposes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Solution 1 :** if you do not absolutely need float as inputs

```
from datetime import datetime, date, time
a = datetime.combine(date.today(), time(0, 6, 58))
b = datetime.combine(date.today(), time(0, 7, 12))
```

**Solution 2** : if your inputs are floats

```
from datetime import datetime, date, time

def float_to_datetime(myfloat):
    minutes, seconds = str(myfloat).split('.')
    return datetime.combine(date.today(), time(0, int(minutes), int(seconds)))

a = float_to_datetime(6.58)
b = float_to_datetime(7.12)
```

In both cases, the output is:

```
print(b - a)
0:00:14
print((b-a).total_seconds())
14.0
```

Comment: I think that works too. I will check it out once I can access python again (school), and then I will tick your answer.